# M Language Multiple json queries for total results

Tags: json, powerbi, powerquery, m

I have a rest api query  that returns me a maximum number of 500 records. I can also get with the api the total number of records.

Because of that I need to merge several queries, to get all my records. Also I need that query to be dynamic and always up to date with the total records.

This is an example code for maximum 1000 records:

```
let
    Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents("https://example.pipedrive.com/v1/deal:(id,title,value,currency)?api_token=12345&limit=500&start=0")),
    Source2 = Json.Document(Web.Contents("https://example.pipedrive.com/v1/deal:(id,title,value,currency)?api_token=12345&limit=500&start=500")),
    data = Source[data],
    data2 = Source2[data],
    #"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(data, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
    #"Converted to Table 2" = Table.FromList(data2, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
    #"Expanded Column1" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Converted to Table", "Column1", {"id", "title", "value", "currency"}, {"Column1.id", "Column1.title", "Column1.value", "Column1.currency"}),
    #"Expanded Column2" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Converted to Table", "Column1", {"id", "title", "value", "currency"}, {"Column1.id", "Column1.title", "Column1.value", "Column1.currency"}),
    #"Appended Query" = Table.Combine({#"Expanded Column1", #"Expanded Column2"})
in
    #"Expanded Column1"
```

My total records are about 11000 and are changing every week.

I can get the total number of records using data.additional_data.total_records.

Can I use this value on a variable, and use some sort of a while, to make a total of querys of (total records / 500)?

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of getting the data and merging the query one by one, you can parameterize the query and convert it into a function.

Let's assume your original query as follows:

```
let
    Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents("https://example.pipedrive.com/v1/deal:(id,title,value,currency)?api_token=12345&limit=500&start=0")),
    data = Source[data],
    #"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(data, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
    #"Expanded Column1" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Converted to Table", "Column1", {"id", "title", "value", "currency"}, {"Column1.id", "Column1.title", "Column1.value", "Column1.currency"})
in
    #"Expanded Column1"
```

You can parameterize the `start` parameter and change the query to a `GetDeal` function as such:

```
(start as text) =>
let
    Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents("https://example.pipedrive.com/v1/deal:(id,title,value,currency)?api_token=12345&limit=500&start=" & start)),
    data = Source[data],
    #"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(data, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
    #"Expanded Column1" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Converted to Table", "Column1", {"id", "title", "value", "currency"}, {"Column1.id", "Column1.title", "Column1.value", "Column1.currency"})
in
    #"Expanded Column1"
```

[image: GetDeal]

Let's say you have the `total_records` stored as a value from another query by navigating to `data.additional_data.total_records`:

[image: total_records]

You can now create a new query and generate a list from `0` up to `total_records`, with an increment of `500`:

```
let
    Source = List.Generate(() => 0, each _ <= (total_records), each _ + 500)
in
    Source
```

[image: list]

Convert it to table and change the column to `text`:

```
let
    Source = List.Generate(() => 0, each _ <= (total_records), each _ + 500),
    #"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(Source, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Converted to Table",{{"Column1", "start"}}),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Renamed Columns",{{"start", type text}})
in
    #"Changed Type"
```

[image: start text]

Now we can invoke the custom function `GetDeal` with the column `start` as :

[image: custom function]

You shall have a list of tables as a new column and can work from there. You can remove the `start` column as it's not needed anymore.

Comment: Big Thanks for this Solution. In the End when I Invoke the Custom Function:

Formula.Firewall: Query 'query_number' (step 'Invoked Custom Function') references other queries or steps, so it may not directly access a data source. Please rebuild this data combination.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't know if it's the same in Powerbi as Excel, but that error usually comes up when you have any non-static reference to an external data source. I always fix it by going to the Query Options>Privacy and setting it to "Always ignore Privacy Level settings". Unless you are actively trying to utilize the Privacy Level settings, they just tend to cause problems.

Comment: @davser Yes I know that could be a potential problem but I deliberately leave it out because the workaround will confuse the understanding of answer above. First you can try what @wedge suggests. If it's not working then the workaround is - you have to put all the three queries (`GetDeal`, `total_records`, `Deal` into the same query. (i.e. wrapping them with let statements and modify the code accordingly) This way you can eliminate the "referencing" that Power BI is complaining, because now they are in the same query.

Comment: @Wedge, your option to "Always ignore Privacy Level settings" fixed the error, Thanks.

Comment: @Foxan-Ng I have used your solution to put all the three queries in one, and that also worked, and it seems the best solution to me, Thanks

Comment: @FoxanNg : wow, another well documented (with screenshots) answer.  You star!

Comment: @s-meaden Glad to help! I usually explain it more clearly so that it can benefit a boarder audience later on :)